# How to convert data frame column list value to element

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Hi I have a dataframe like this:

```
        A
   0    []
   1    [1234] 
   2    []
```

I want to change it into:

```
        A
   0    0
   1    1234 
   2    0
```

How can I do that?

I tries with

```
df['A'] = [a[0] if len(a) > 0 else 0 for a in df['A']]
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried already and why your approach isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First idea is select first value, replace missing values to `0` from empty lists and last convert to integers:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str[0].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Or use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) by mask with compare lenghts of lists:

```
df['A'] = np.where(df['A'].str.len() == 0, 0, df['A'].str[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:
(assuming all elements of column A are of type list)

```
df['A'] = [a[0] if len(a) > 0 else 0 for a in df['A']]
```

otherwise (making sure that the element is a list before accessing the first element:

```
df['A'] = [a if isinstance(a, int) else (a[0] if a else 0) for a in df['A']]
```

Comment: It's very fast. It can be simplified: [a[0] if a else 0 for a in df['A']]

Comment: TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len() using this code ..

Comment: The way your example is set up, it seems that every element of col A is a list..

Comment: @jainamshah I made the required changes